# Capistrano doesn't support svn 1.8+?

Tags: svn, capistrano

I'm deploying my app by Capistrano

- ruby 2.0
- capistrano (2.15.5)
- capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
- railsless-deploy (1.1.2)

It works well with svn 1.7.
But with svn 1.6, It won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of a bug of Capistrano :

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/3b1f1da1824b7f40ac06ad5655621716e077543b#lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/subversion.rb

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Reverting to Capistrano 2.14.2 (not 2.15.x) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion 1.8 introduces a new working copy database format, and it's not automatically upgraded. If your working copy is accessed by both 1.8 and 1.7 client libraries, the 1.7 clients will fail after the 1.8 client has upgraded the database format.

Comment: executing locally: "svn info {svnurl} --username \"{username}\"--password \"{password}\"--no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
executing locally: "svn info {svnurl} --username {username} --password {password} --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"

Answer (score 0):

I found a defference in option of svn command which is automatically execuyted by capstrano.

svn 1.7 (fail)

```
executing locally: "svn info {svnurl} --username\"{username}\"--password \"{password}\"--no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
```

svn 1.6 (success)

```
executing locally: "svn info {svnurl} --username {username} --password {password} --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
```

Comment: In the original post, you said 1.7 worked and 1.8 failed. Now you're saying 1.7 fails and previous versions succeed. This inconsistency makes your Q&A very difficult for someone else to use if they think they've encountered a similar problem.